# Dynamic yet restrained element width?

Tags: html, css

http://jsbin.com/upohag/1/edit

The blue div should take up the space between the green and purple divs. I don't know the width of the green div, but as it gets bigger, the width of the blue should get smaller.

edit: I'd like to do this without tables or javascript.

In the example here (with tables, but only to demonstrate what I mean): http://jsbin.com/upohag/2/edit, the blue rectangle fits snugly between the other two. One problem, though, is that the left rectangle doesn't take up all the space it needs. The left rectangle should be able to fully expand.

Comment: What's your objection to tables? They are literally perfectly suited to this.

Comment: @nneonneo, I'm trying to refrain from using tables for non-tabular data. I also don't like having to tack on the table, tbody, tr, and td elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display: table-cell` to get the right auto-sizing behaviour:

```
.left{
  display:table-cell;
} 
.center{
  display:table-cell;
}
.right{
  display:table-cell;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/upohag/12/edit